# Load multiple images in ImageView

Tags: android, gridview, imageview, universal-image-loader

I have a grid view which shows some images loaded from a server. I use Universal image loader to load the images in the imageView. the problem is it takes time to load those images and I don't want their places to be empty. I want to show an image which is located in the assets of the app and then load the images from server on top of it. 
I wanted to ask if you have any solutions to this problem.
Thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very generic way to use `DisplayImageOptions` is as

```
DisplayImageOptions displayImageOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.placeholder_image).showImageForEmptyUri(0)
            .resetViewBeforeLoading(true).cacheInMemory(true).cacheOnDisk(true)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT).bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .delayBeforeLoading(100).displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(500)).build();
```

Here `showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.placeholder_image)` method is used to display a placeholder image until the real image is loaded. `R.drawable.placeholder_image` is the drawable you want to show as placeholder.

Comment: Thanks very much , I missed it :)